# Mysql count number combination between 6 columns

Tags: php, mysql

I've been searching all around but I still couldn't find a solution yet. What I am trying to do is to build a function that counts all combinations of `1,2,3,4,5,6` unique possibilities in the database.

Example

Given the numbers `01,02,03,04,05,06` in columns `a,b,c,d,e,f`

(the numbers don't repeat horizontally)

1) Check all unique combinations and count the repetition

Counts x Combination (example)

```
10 - 01,02,03,04,05,06   
09 - 01,02,03,04,05    
08 - 01,02,03,04         
07 - 01,02,03           
06 - 01,02               
05 - 01
```

[UPDATE]

To be more clear I have 6 columns filled with random numbers (01-60) as 02 05 09 22 32 33

What I need to do is check and count wether (02 05) is repeated in the entire column or (02 09), (02 22), (02 32)... Then do the same with (02 05 09)... (02 05 09 22)... (02 05 09 22 32)... 
(02 05 09 22 32 33)...

I tried using this line but it only counts the combination of 2 numbers between the first 2 columns

```
Select d1, d2, count(*) as 'count' from tb group by d1, d2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your examples are not "all combination possibilities".

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Thanks for helping. Still unsolved.

Comment: you probably won't get a good answer because your question is not clear.. what the hell are you talking about?

Comment: Hi. What information do you need @Pamblam? Thanks!

Comment: you're only two votes from having your question closed for being unclear so you better figure it out soon..

Comment: I've just included more information. Thank you @Pamblam

Comment: here's what i got from your update: you have a table full of numbers and you have some other numbers, somehow you want to make a combination using the numbers in the database and compare it the other numbers... you're not saying how you're combining them, you're not saying what you're actually checking for.. you're just throwing numbers at us screaming "fix it"...

Comment: It is exactly as explained. Example: First I would combine in 2 (00,00) and check this combination repetition within these 6 columns. Then combine in 3 (00,00,00) and so on... Thanks! @Pamblam

Comment: Is this an impossible question?

Comment: Maybe too heavy, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for count of repetition group by possible combination

Try this

```
SELECT 
count(*) repetition,CONCAT(A,', ',B,', ',C,', ',D,', ',E,', ',F) combination 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY CONCAT(A,B,C,D,E,F)
```

Comment: Do I need to concat? ( a,b,c,d,e,f are columns)

Comment: You must need to Group them to get count of that combination.

Comment: It doesn't display anything

Comment: Can you share database schema if possible?